# Model interval inclusiveness in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, interval

This is my first attempt to model a day's time interval and the fact that the start and end are either inclusive or not:

```
public class UtcTimeOfDay
{
    public int HourOfDay { get; set; }
    public int MinuteOfDay { get; set; }
    public int SecondOfDay { get; set; }
}

public class UtcTimeInterval
{
    public UtcTimeOfDay StartUtcTimeOfDay { get; set; }
    public UtcTimeOfDay EndUtcTimeOfDay { get; set; }
    public bool StartInclusive { get; set; }
    public bool EndInclusive { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need `UtcTimeOfDay` at all? `DateTime` already has useful methods for working with paramterized times.

The disadvantage that using a raw `DateTime` has is that you have no compile-time guarantee that you won't get an invalid `DateTime` (e.g. one with a `Day` component above 0). However, you can get the best of both worlds by having your class *wrap* a `DateTime`:

```
public class UtcTimeOfDay
{
    public readonly DateTime Value;

    public UtcTimeOfDay(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {
        Value = new DateTime(0,0,0,hour,minute,second);
    }
}
```

Now you get all the advantages of the rich functionality of `DateTime`, along with the guarantees provided by your original class.

---

Regarding your original `UtcTimeOfDay`, the names aren't great. Shouldn't `MinuteOfDay` be `MinuteOfHour`, and likewise shouldn't `SecondOfDay` be `SecondOfMinute`?

This also reveals another problem: there's no guarantee that these values are valid (they could be negative, or above the maximum possible). This could be done with validation in a constructor, making the setters `private`.

---

The name `UtcTimeInterval` doesn't make any reference to the fact that it's specifically for a time interval within a day. Why not `UtcTimeOfDayInterval`?

---

While you can use `StartInclusive` and `EndInclusive`, a normal technique to deal with exclusive time spans is simply to add or subtract a tick to your time. So for example, if the inclusive start time was `startTimeInclusive`, then if you want an exclusive version, that would be `startTimeExclusive = startTimeInclusive.AddTicks(1);`

Being able to do this so simply is another benefit of using a `DateTime` rather than trying to roll your own structure to represent the same thing.

So what I would do is remove the `StartInclusive` and `EndInclusive` properties, and do one of the following:

- Just let whoever sets the start and end `UtcTimeOfDay` take responsibility for adding or subtracting a tick if they need to.
- Add a constructor with boolean `startInclusive` and `endInclusive` parameters, as well as the start and end `UtcTimeOfDay`s which itself does the tick adding/subtracting when needed.

---

### Update

As a couple of people have noted in comments, using a `TimeSpan` instead of a `DateTime` may be preferable, as it is more in fitting with the meaning of these structures. This makes the add/subtract tick logic slightly more verbose, but not prohibitively.

Comment: The most common way of indicating a time of day in .NET is a `TimeSpan` representing the time since midnight.

Comment: @JonHanna Interesting. I can see why that might be more natural than what I described.

Comment: Indeed, the code you have here will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` while conversly, `DateTime.TimeOfDay` is an example where `TimeSpan` does this rôle in the BCL.

Comment: Time since midnight fails with daylight savings

Comment: @Ewan Can you give an example of that?

Comment: usualy daylight saving lose/gain an hour at 1am so your 7am start might be 6 or 8 hours since midnight

Comment: you also have leap seconds to worry about on jan 1st

Answer (score 4):

### In general:

- Put them in a `namespace` so they don't pollute the global namespace.
- Are you aware of the .NET `struct DateTime` and `struct TimeSpan` ? They do almost exactly what you're looking for. Why don't you make use of them?
- Part of the reason to use `class`es is so that you can define them to behave consistently. `UtcTimeInterval` is a poor abstraction for what you're trying to do, for a number of reasons:

  - It doesn't enforce a canonical representation. There are multiple possible representations of a time, say 2am: `HourOfDay=1; MinuteOfDay=60` and `HourOfDay=2; MinuteOfDay=0;` It's even possible for a time that is actually later to be compared as lexicographically earlier. Also are negatives supposed to be possible
  - The data structure is supposed to only allow itself to be set to sensible values. If nonsense is put in, it should throw an exception or mark itself invalid.
  - And, have you considered [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)?
  - Why are you using "1 second" as the smallest nonzero interval? Many applications need finer-grained than that.
- Neither class supports any operations except the defaults for the class: assignment, equality, comparison. Why is there no method that takes two `UtcTimeOfDay`s and returns a `UtcTimeInterval`? What are these classes going to be used for?

Comment: Ok makes all sense. There are certain reason for my choice but your point reg. canonical representation I take def. on board.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the pleasure of working with periods of time which start at a particular time of the day and I ended up with a similar Hour/min/sec of day structure to yours, although it confuses me that you call it UTCTimeOfDay?

The problems with modeling things like shifts which start at 7:30am with the standard date time objects are

1: Timezones! this is why the UTC part of your struct confuses me. normally you would want the shift (or whatever) to start at 7:30am local time where ever in the world the shop is.

2: Daylight savings, This stops you using TimeSpan, 7 and a half hours since midnight is not always 7:30am

Storing int hour,min and second is really your only good solution

But then you have the problem of calculating the difference between two of these 'time of days'. This gives you the same problems but in reverse. you have to convert '7:30am' to '7:30am on this particular day in this particular timezone' then again with the end TimeOfDay. once thats done you can use the standard datetime - datetime = timespan to work out the actual elapsed time

Again its non intuitive when the shift covers daylight saving changes, leap years etc

Start and End Inclusive/Exclusiveness is only really a problem when you are looking for overlaps. I always treat the end as exclusive and the start as inclusive. This allows midnight to midnight to be one day rather than having 12:59:59.9999 mucking up your maths